# How to select document by id with Sails-mongo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, sails-mongo

```
User.find({ _id: { '!': user.id } }, function foundFriends (err, friends) {
    if(err) return next(err);
        res.view({
            friends: friends
        });
});

MONGODB :

 {
    _id: ObjectId("53b942f7c8638f7b17670acc"),
    name: "PH",
    admin: true,
    online: false,
    encryptedPassword: "$2a$10$PjcPRgL67ZSOWDjmEwTkvu30xKeDXdCwgZ.D0.bjyDRw9sOfS/4UK",
    createdAt: ISODate("2014-07-06T12:37:11.522Z"),
    updatedAt: ISODate("2014-07-09T18:22:47.25Z")
}
```

This Code doesn't work, I would like to select document by Id. I don't know what I should do to fix that in my sails project. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of things I see are weird with your code.
1. The callback function as for sails 10 should be executed with .exec()
2. I think you should not search for `_id` but only `id`. I think waterline parses this underscore.

Having that in mind your code should look something like

```
User.find({ id: { '!': user.id } }).exec(function (err, friends) {
    if(err) return next(err);
    res.view({
        friends: friends
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can try this for find, update, or destroy by id with sails-mongo via `select`:

```
 //Schema
  module.exports = {  
   autoPK : false,
     attributes : {
       id : {
         type: 'string',
         primaryKey: true
       },
       name : {
         type : 'string'
       },
       email : {
         type : 'string'
       }
    }
 }



 // Find
 User.find({
   select : {id : user.id}
 }).exec((err,record)=> { 
   if(err) return console.log(err,"err");
   console.log(record,"record");
 })

 // Update
 User.update({
   select : {id : user.id}
 },{ 
  name : "Foo"
 }).exec((err,record)=> { 
   if(err) return console.log(err,"err");
   console.log(record,"record");
 })

 // Destroy
 User.destroy({
   select : {id : user.id}
 }).exec((err,record)=> { 
   if(err) return console.log(err,"err");
   console.log(record,"record");
 })
```

Hope this can help to you.

Comment: mongo specifies its own id for every document created. adding a separate field for id therefore becomes redundant

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
User.findOne({ _id : ObjectId(user.id.toString()) })
```

Hope this help.