# Remove mongo document by id in Sails-mongo not working

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, objectid, oid

I have `objId($oid)` of the document and I am trying to remove the document in Sails by using destroy function

`User.destroy({id:objId}).exec(cb);`

It is not working. I tried [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661635/how-to-select-document-by-id-with-sails-mongo) from 
other post. But it does not work either.I tried using `Mongo` `ObjectId` function too but it does not work either. 
Any suggestions.
I can use native function but  prefer not to.

Comment: Can you provide any more information, such as an error received? 

Try 
    `User.destroy(objId).exec(function(err, destroyed){
       if(err) {...}  else {...}
    });`

Comment: @metzuda I tried User.findOne(objId).exec(function(e,r){console.log(e,r)}) to see if passing just objId works. Does not show any error. Prints null and undefined.

Comment: if `r` is returning undefined then that usually means it doesn't exist in the database.

Comment: Objid I am trying to query does exist. I tried User.find({id:User.mongo.objectId(objId)}).exec(function(e,r){console.log(r)). It returns entire user collection instead of specific user. Do I have to use _id?

Answer (score 0):

In your model try to change the type of id as objectid and hope it works

```
module.exports={
    id : {
       type : objectid
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use ObjectId in any operation with mongoDb , you can try to load the native lib first as this example

var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

User.native(function (err, collection) {
  collection.update({_id: new ObjectId(anIdVariable)},{$push:{pubs:aPubsVariable}}, function (err) {
});

Works for me also to remove document :

collection.deleteOne({ _id :ObjectId("5920263cce3510410d492489") }, function(err, result) {
}